# Show both 'active' and 'inactive' plots in knitr html output

Tags: r, plot, knitr

For several correspondence analysis packages, single `plot` function generates multiple plots. The first plot is `active`, and the rest are `inactive`. Is there a way to print all plots one after another in the `knitr` html output. I am trying the following, which is not working.

````
```{r fig.keep='all'}
library(CAvariants)

data(asbestos)
head(asbestos)
str(asbestos)
CAvariants(asbestos, catype = "CA", firstaxis = 1, lastaxis = 2)
CAvariants(asbestos, catype = "DOCA", firstaxis = 1,lastaxis = 2)
CAvariants(asbestos, catype = "DONSCA",firstaxis=1, lastaxis = 2, ellcomp = FALSE)

risasbestos<-CAvariants(asbestos, catype = "DOCA", firstaxis=1, lastaxis=2)
plot(risasbestos, plotype = "biplot", biptype = "row") 

```
````

Answer (score 0):

The function plot.CAvariant has several calls to dev.new() which knitr does not handle well. What you can do is manually edit the function to remove those calls as following :

````
---
title: "Test"
ouptut: html_document
---
```{r fig.keep='all'}
library(CAvariants)

data(asbestos)
head(asbestos)
str(asbestos)
plot.CAvariants <-
    function (x, firstaxis = 1, lastaxis = 2, cex = 0.8, cex.lab = 0.8, 
            prop = 1, plottype = "biplot", biptype = "row", scaleplot = 1, 
            posleg = "topleft", pos = 2, ell = FALSE, Mell = x$Mell, 
            alpha = 0.05, ...) 
{
  if ((firstaxis < 1) | (firstaxis > x$r)) 
    stop(paste("incorrect first axis =", firstaxis, "\n\n"))
  if (lastaxis > x$r) 
    stop(paste("incorrect last axis =", lastaxis, "\n\n"))
  if (firstaxis >= lastaxis) 
    stop(paste("last axis must be greater than first axis\n\n"))
  n <- sum(x$Xtable)
  I <- nrow(x$Xtable)
  rowgroup <- list(1:x$rows, rep(1, x$rows))
  rowgrlab <- list(1, "", "*", "red", "T")
  colgroup <- list(1:x$cols, rep(1, x$cols))
  colgrlab <- list(1, "", "+", "blue", "T")
  if ((plottype == "Classical") | (plottype == "classical") | 
      (plottype == "classic") | (plottype == "c")) {
    nthings <- x$cols
    nvars <- x$rows
    cord1 <- x$Cprinccoord
    cord2 <- x$Rprinccoord
    dmu = diag(x$inertias[, 1])
    inertiapc = x$inertias[, 2]
    dimnames(cord1)[1] <- dimnames(x$Xtable)[2]
    dimnames(cord2)[1] <- dimnames(x$Xtable)[1]
    thinggroup <- colgroup
    thinggrlab <- colgrlab
    vargroup <- rowgroup
    vargrlab <- rowgrlab
    thinglabels <- x$collabels
    varlabels <- x$rowlabels
    main = "Classical plot"
    if ((x$catype == "DONSCA") | (x$catype == "DOCA") | (x$catype == 
          "SOCA") | (x$catype == "SONSCA")) {
      cat("\n ERROR: NO CLASSICAL PLOT for ordered analysis. ONLY A BIPLOT can be constructed  (Please change 'plottype' and specify 'biptype')\n")
      stop()
    }
  }
  if ((plottype == "Biplot") | (plottype == "biplot") | (plottype == 
        "bip") | (plottype == "b")) {
    if ((biptype == "rows") | (biptype == "Rows") | (biptype == 
          "row") | (biptype == "r")) {
      plottype <- "biplot"
      cord1 <- x$Rprinccoord * scaleplot
      cord2 <- x$Cstdcoord/scaleplot
      nthings <- x$rows
      nvars <- x$cols
      thinglabels <- x$rowlabels
      varlabels <- x$collabels
      thinggroup <- rowgroup
      thinggrlab <- rowgrlab
      vargroup <- colgroup
      vargrlab <- colgrlab
      main <- "Row Isometric Biplot"
      inertiapc = x$inertias[, 2]
      dmu = diag(x$inertias[, 1])
      dimnames(cord2)[1] <- dimnames(x$Xtable)[2]
      dimnames(cord1)[1] <- dimnames(x$Xtable)[1]
      if ((x$catype == "DONSCA") | (x$catype == "DOCA") | 
          (x$catype == "SOCA") | (x$catype == "SONSCA")) {
        cord2 <- x$Rprinccoord * scaleplot
        cord1 <- x$Cstdcoord/scaleplot
        nthings <- x$cols
        nvars <- x$rows
        thinglabels <- x$collabels
        varlabels <- x$rowlabels
        thinggroup <- colgroup
        thinggrlab <- colgrlab
        vargroup <- rowgroup
        vargrlab <- rowgrlab
        inertiapc = x$inertias2[, 2]
        dmu = diag(x$inertias2[, 1])
        dimnames(cord2)[1] <- dimnames(x$Xtable)[1]
        dimnames(cord1)[1] <- dimnames(x$Xtable)[2]
      }
    }
    else {
      plottype <- "biplot"
      if (ell == TRUE) {
        scaleplot <- 1
      }
      if ((x$catype == "CA") | (x$catype == "NSCA")) {
        cord1 <- x$Cprinccoord * scaleplot
        cord2 <- x$Rstdcoord/scaleplot
        nthings <- x$cols
        nvars <- x$rows
        thinggroup <- colgroup
        thinggrlab <- colgrlab
        vargroup <- rowgroup
        vargrlab <- rowgrlab
        thinglabels <- x$collabels
        varlabels <- x$rowlabels
        main <- "Column Isometric Biplot"
        inertiapc = x$inertias[, 2]
        dmu = diag(x$inertias[, 1])
        dimnames(cord1)[1] <- dimnames(x$Xtable)[2]
        dimnames(cord2)[1] <- dimnames(x$Xtable)[1]
      }
      if ((x$catype == "DONSCA") | (x$catype == "DOCA") | 
          (x$catype == "SOCA") | (x$catype == "SONSCA")) {
        if (ell == TRUE) {
          scaleplot <- 1
        }
        cord2 <- x$Cprinccoord * scaleplot
        cord1 <- x$Rstdcoord/scaleplot
        nthings <- x$rows
        nvars <- x$cols
        thinggroup <- rowgroup
        thinggrlab <- rowgrlab
        vargroup <- colgroup
        vargrlab <- colgrlab
        thinglabels <- x$rowlabels
        varlabels <- x$collabels
        inertiapc = x$inertias[, 2]
        dmu = diag(x$inertias[, 1])
        dimnames(cord1)[1] <- dimnames(x$Xtable)[1]
        dimnames(cord2)[1] <- dimnames(x$Xtable)[2]
      }
    }
  }
  if ((x$catype == "DOCA") | (x$catype == "SOCA") | (x$catype == 
        "SONSCA") | (x$catype == "DONSCA")) {
    cat("\n Looking at the Trends of rows and columns\n")
    trendplot(x$mj, (x$Trend), posleg = posleg, main = "Reconstructed rows of the centred column profile", 
        xlab = "ordered scores", prop = prop)

    trendplot(x$mi, t(x$Trend), posleg = posleg, main = "Reconstructed columns of the centred column profile", 
        xlab = "ordered scores", prop = prop)
  }
  picsize1 <- c(range(cord1[, c(firstaxis, lastaxis)], cord2[, 
              c(firstaxis, lastaxis)])/prop)
  if (picsize1[1] >= picsize1[2]) 
    stop(paste("incorrect axis scale picsize =", picsize1[1], 
            picsize1[2], "\n\n"))
  if ((x$catype == "DONSCA") || (x$catype == "DOCA")) {
    plotone(firstaxis, lastaxis, plottype = plottype, things = x$catype, 
        nthings, nvars, cord1, cord2, inertiapc = round(inertiapc, 
            digits = 1), thinggroup, thinggrlab, vargroup, 
        vargrlab, thinglabels, varlabels, picsize = picsize1, 
        cex = cex, cex.lab = cex.lab, type = "b", catype = x$catype, 
        pos = pos)
  }
  if ((x$catype == "SOCA") || (x$catype == "SONSCA")) {
    if (biptype == "row") {
      type = "b"
    }
    else {
      type = "p"
    }
    plotone(firstaxis, lastaxis, plottype = plottype, things = x$catype, 
        nthings, nvars, cord1, cord2, inertiapc = round(inertiapc, 
            digits = 1), thinggroup, thinggrlab, vargroup, 
        vargrlab, thinglabels, varlabels, picsize = picsize1, 
        cex = cex, cex.lab = cex.lab, catype = x$catype, 
        type = type, pos = pos)
  }
  if ((x$catype == "CA") || (x$catype == "NSCA")) {
    plotone(firstaxis, lastaxis, plottype = plottype, things = x$catype, 
        nthings, nvars, cord1, cord2, inertiapc = round(inertiapc, 
            digits = 1), thinggroup, thinggrlab, vargroup, 
        vargrlab, thinglabels, varlabels, picsize = picsize1, 
        cex = cex, cex.lab = cex.lab, type = "p", catype = x$catype, 
        pos = pos)
  }
  if (ell == TRUE) {
    if (((x$catype == "NSCA") | (x$catype == "CA") | (x$catype == 
            "DOCA") | (x$catype == "SOCA") | (x$catype == "SONSCA") | 
          (x$catype == "DONSCA")) & (plottype == "biplot") & 
        (biptype == "row") | (biptype == "r") | (biptype == 
          "rows")) {
      cordr <- cord2
      cordc <- cord1
      cord1 <- cordr
      cord2 <- cordc
    }
    switch(x$catype, CA = caellipse(Xtable = x$Xtable, a1 = firstaxis, 
            a2 = lastaxis, alpha = alpha, M = Mell, cex = cex, 
            cex.lab = cex.lab, prop = prop, Imass = x$Imass, 
            Jmass = x$Jmass, a = x$Rstdcoord, b = x$Cstdcoord, 
            g = cord1, fr = cord2, dmu = dmu, inertiapc = round(inertiapc, 
                digits = 1), plottype = plottype, biptype = biptype, 
            pos = pos, arrow = TRUE, length = 0, graphy = TRUE, 
            ell = TRUE), SOCA = caellipse(Xtable = x$Xtable, 
            a1 = firstaxis, a2 = lastaxis, alpha = alpha, M = Mell, 
            cex = cex, cex.lab = cex.lab, prop = prop, Imass = x$Imass, 
            Jmass = x$Jmass, a = solve(x$Imass^0.5) %*% x$Rstdcoord, 
            b = solve(x$Jmass^0.5) %*% x$Cstdcoord, g = cord2, 
            fr = cord1, dmu = dmu, inertiapc = round(inertiapc, 
                digits = 1), plottype = plottype, biptype = biptype, 
            pos = pos, arrow = FALSE, length = 0, graphy = T, 
            ell = TRUE), DOCA = caellipse(Xtable = x$Xtable, 
            a1 = firstaxis, a2 = lastaxis, alpha = alpha, M = Mell, 
            cex = cex, cex.lab = cex.lab, prop = prop, Imass = x$Imass, 
            Jmass = x$Jmass, a = solve(x$Imass^0.5) %*% x$Rstdcoord, 
            b = solve(x$Jmass^0.5) %*% x$Cstdcoord, g = cord2, 
            fr = cord1, dmu = dmu, inertiapc = round(inertiapc, 
                digits = 1), plottype = plottype, biptype = biptype, 
            pos = pos, arrow = FALSE, length = 0, graphy = T, 
            ell = TRUE), NSCA = nscaellipse(Xtable = x$Xtable, 
            a1 = firstaxis, a2 = lastaxis, alpha = alpha, M = Mell, 
            cex = cex, cex.lab = cex.lab, prop = prop, Imass = x$Imass, 
            Jmass = x$Jmass, a = x$Rstdcoord, b = x$Cstdcoord, 
            g = cord1, fr = cord2, dmu = dmu, tauden = x$tauden, 
            inertiapc = round(inertiapc, digits = 1), plottype = plottype, 
            biptype = biptype, pos = pos, arrow = T, length = 0, 
            graphy = T, ell = TRUE), SONSCA = nscaellipse(Xtable = x$Xtable, 
            a1 = firstaxis, a2 = lastaxis, alpha = alpha, M = Mell, 
            cex = cex, cex.lab = cex.lab, prop = prop, Imass = x$Imass, 
            Jmass = x$Jmass, a = x$Rstdcoord, b = x$Cstdcoord, 
            g = cord2, fr = cord1, dmu = dmu, tauden = x$tauden, 
            inertiapc = round(inertiapc, digits = 1), plottype = plottype, 
            biptype = biptype, pos = pos, arrow = FALSE, length = 0, 
            graphy = T, ell = TRUE), DONSCA = nscaellipse(Xtable = x$Xtable, 
            a1 = firstaxis, a2 = lastaxis, alpha = alpha, M = Mell, 
            cex = cex, cex.lab = cex.lab, prop = prop, Imass = x$Imass, 
            Jmass = x$Jmass, a = x$Rstdcoord, b = x$Cstdcoord, 
            g = cord2, fr = cord1, dmu = dmu, tauden = x$tauden, 
            inertiapc = round(inertiapc, digits = 1), plottype = plottype, 
            biptype = biptype, pos = pos, arrow = FALSE, length = 0, 
            graphy = T, ell = TRUE))
  }
}
plot(CAvariants(asbestos, catype = "CA", firstaxis = 1, lastaxis = 2))
plot(CAvariants(asbestos, catype = "DOCA", firstaxis = 1,lastaxis = 2))
plot(CAvariants(asbestos, catype = "DONSCA",firstaxis=1, lastaxis = 2, ellcomp = FALSE))

risasbestos<-CAvariants(asbestos, catype = "DOCA", firstaxis=1, lastaxis=2)
plot(risasbestos, plotype = "biplot", biptype = "row") 

```
````